# jQuery Checkboxes to Populate Mutlidimensional Array

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, multidimensional-array, populate

I have a list of checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="cb1" value2="value01" class="sort" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="cb2" value2="value02" class="sort" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="cb3" value2="value03" class="sort" />
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="cb4" value2="value04" class="sort" />
```

And what I would like to do, is when I toggle these on or off, they populate an Multidimensional array (Arr_Sort[0][1]), just two levels ONLY.

Here's my script code that works fine to populate a single dimensional array, I just don't know how to modify it to populate a multidimensional array.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".sort").change(function()
    {
        var arr_sort = new Array();

        $(".sort").each(function()
        {
            if( $(this).is(':checked') )
            {
                arr_sort.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
        alert( arr_sort );
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't understood what you want to populate your multidimensional array with. Simple array is clear, but on multi? Give additional information of how you want it to looks like

Comment: what is the value of `Arr_Sort[0][1]` supposed to be?

Comment: I wish Arr_Sort to be [["cb1", "value01"], ["cb2", "value02"], ["cb3","value03"], ["cb4","value04"]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing `arr_sort.push( $( this ).val() );`

with

```
arr_sort.push( new Array( $( this ).val(), $( this ).attr( 'value2' ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var arr_sort = [];
    $(".sort").change(function(){
        $(this).each(function(key,val){
            if( $(this).is(':checked') ){
                arr_sort[ $(this).index() + 1] = $(this).val();
            }else{
                arr_sort.remove($(this).val());
            }
        });
        console.log( arr_sort );
    });
});

Array.prototype.remove = function() {
    var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
    while (L && this.length) {
        what = a[--L];
        while ((ax = this.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
            this.splice(ax, 1);
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

1. Declare ARRAY as [] to improve performance.
2. declare array out of change function.
3. Handle negative scenario also, If the value is removed, it should be removed from the array.